# Delete rows based on REGEX pattern match excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I would like to use a macro in excel to delete rows if the cell value does not match regex expression. 
More specifically, if the cell value does not start with a digit, delete the whole row

**Example**

before macro

[image]

after macro

[image]

So I've been trying to piece together some code from forums using .AutoFilter but I don't think it takes a regex object as criteria, only strings..

```
Sub test()
    Dim table As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim upperLeft As Range
    Dim digitOnly As Object

    Set digitOnly = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    digitOnly.Pattern = "^[\d]"
    digitOnly.Ignorecase = True

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set upperLeft = ws.Range("A2")
    Set table = upperLeft.CurrentRegion

    With table
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=digitOnly
    .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    End Sub
```

Could someone please suggest an alternative or perhaps tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you :).

Comment: Loop over the rows (typically from the bottom up) and delete the rows where `Not Cells(n, 1).Value Like "#*"`  You don't need the vbscript regexp for this one.  Check out the posts liked under "Related" on this page.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to attempt this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim table As Range, c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set table = ws.Range("A2").CurrentRegion

    For i = table.columns(1).cells.count to 2 Step -1
        With table.columns(1).cells(i)
            If Not .Value like "#*" then .EntireRow.Delete
        End with  
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @PaichengWu recommendation, I used his LIKE expression and read some other related [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27471504/12140788):

```
Sub DeleteRow()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Not Range("A" & i).Value Like "#*" Then
            Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Happy Chap :)
Thanks.